# NSWindow ignore mouse/keyboard events

Tags: cocoa, events, user-controls, nswindow, nswindowcontroller

At this time I'm developing a Cocoa application, that is formed by a main `NSWindowController`, where all the application data is showed and some others `NSWindowControllers` that will appear, like a formulary, when the user needs to edit or add more data to the main `NSWindowController` window.

My problem is that when i need to add or edit data in these formularies, the main `NSWindowController` can't have any kind of user interaction, to prevent any change in the main `NSWindowController`'s displayed information.

I've already tried `-(void)setIgnoresMouseEvents:(BOOL)flag` but this solution makes the main NSWindowController completely transparent to interaction, making any accidental click, interact with any window bellow thus hiding the application.

Does anyone knows of a better solution?

Comment: Remember that you can accept your own answers. Please accept it: this will mark question as answered.

Comment: Thank you for this question, as it accidentally answered a question I just had: how to ignore all mouse events!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found what i was looking for:

```
[NSApp runModalForWindow:(NSWindow *)aWindow];
```

In this way, i can prevent any interaction with the mother Window until i close the child windows and do:

```
[NSApp stopModal];
```

so that it becomes active again.